# iPhone App: How to implement horizontal knob as shown in image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to implement horizontal knob where user can set the value moving the knob

[image]

[image]

Here as shown image how to set the distance value from picker (horizontal nob)?

How can I achieve that?

Comment: use ScrollView to scroll horizontally and display value in separate UIViews. i think it may not be pickerview.It looks like that.You can design like that and place there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an UIPickerView modified with *CGAffineTransform* - to scale it and rotate it by 90 degrees. That you would get the notifications on what component the user did select, by implementing the standard UIPickerDelegate methods.

You'd need to supply the labels by using the

```
- (UIView *)viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

method, and rotate them by -90 degrees to appear correctly aligned - also, the transformation applied to the picker could distort the views too, so you'd may have to upscale them.

It would take some trial and error to make it look perfect, but it seems easily doable. And I think that's what they used in the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a colour picker wheel like that using a horizontal table:

```
tableView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

I guess you would have to transform the labels inside the table too - I didn't have to because my colour picker was just coloured squares.